# Accessing database table through other table in php

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, erd

I am working on a project with a bigger database structure then I have ever used before. I have questions regarding accessing certain tables.

I am now designing my ERD and have several Module tables
"Modules", "SubModules1" and "SubModules2".

As shown in the diagram below, Modules has an 1-m relation with SubModules1 and SubModules1 has a 1-m relationship with SubModules. There is a Bugs Table in which I want to store bugs linked to the module or submodule it belongs.

**Question:**

Is it necessary to connect all the Module Tables with Bugs Table separately, or is it possible to access all the SubModules through the Module table, since that one is connected to the SubModule1, etc...?

*Note: Requirement is Data must be accessed from DB using PHP + Laravel 5.3 Framework*

[image]

Comment: Yes using laravels hasMany relationship would allow you to access the submodules from modules

Comment: This works just fine thanks!

Comment: @AntonyThompson Hey just another question, if the Module table hasMany Bugs, then the Bugs table can't acces the  submodules can it? Then the Bugs table has to hasMany Modules in order for that to work. But in that case 1 bug can have multiple modules. am I right? Or will it work they way I want to

Comment: For the structure you have. Module hasMany Bugs and Bugs belongsTo Modules. Then you could go Bugs->Modules->SubModules1->SubModules2. So if you want you don't have to have have a Submoduels1 and 2 id in your bugs table. But that depends on if you need it or not

Comment: Thanks again! You are a great help :)